# How to make auth with callback hell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

Create a auth system. When user make a `post`-query (`router.js`):

```
var user = require("../controllers/user");

router.post("/login", function(req, res, next){
    user.login(req, function(result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
```

File controllers/user.js:

```
var mongo = require("./mongo");

exports.login = function (req, callback) {
    var res;
    var login = req.body.login,
        password = req.body.password;

    var user = new mongo.User({
        login: login,
        password: password
    });

    //check if exist user
    user.findOne({
        login: login
    }, function (err, obj) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("user not found -> save");
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    callback("OK");
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("ELSE");
            if (password == obj["password"]) {
                callback("OK");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want when user.login will finished create/make new user -> call callback with result.

```
exports.login = function(req, callback){
user.findOne(/...login or sign up new user.../);
callback("Success");
}
```

So in case when user authorized ->

```
user.login(req, function(result) {
        res.send(result); //this executes
    });
```

How to make this?

Comment: You need to add callback in case of errors too. So, make callback to take two parameters (error, response). If there is error then call `callback("error msg", null)` and in case of success `callback(null, "OK")`. Otherwise the code looks good. Is there any trouble calling callback ?

Comment: The typical way to resolve callback hell is to start using promises. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @PhagunBaya thanks for response. I added `callback(error, result)` to hande errors too. Code just isn't working :)
XmlHttpRequest on client-side said `500: Internal Server Error`. All working, except `user.findOne` function, because it doesn't call the callback. Problem with syntax, I think...

Comment: @Tomalak, I just don't understand why promises need at all. Know that they are something like instead XmlHttpRequest...do they?

Comment: Are you using any npm library for mongo interaction ? If yes then can you please point it to me ? I want to see the implementation of user.findOne function.

Comment: No, that's not at all what promises are. I recommend you take the time to read up on them, they can greatly simplify asynchronous code. (And yes, some HTTP request libraries use them as well for that reason.)

Comment: @PhagunBaya, Mongoose use. 
Code: https://jsfiddle.net/uan4df7j/1/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was in syntax, when I tried to find user using `user.findOne()`.
Instead `user.findOne()` I use `mongo.User.findOne()`:

```
 //mongo.User because I required a mongo.js, where connect to db
// where I had a User model
           mongo.User.findOne({ login: login }, function(err, user){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    if(user) {
                        if(password == user["password"]) {
                            resolve("Login success.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("new user creating...");
                    var newUser = new mongo.User({ login: login, password: password });
                    newUser.save(function(err){
                        if(err) {
                            reject(err);
                            console.log("error with saving");
                        } else {
                            resolve("New user created.")
                        }
                    })
                    }
                }
            });
```

Also I have used a Promises (as said user [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)), so code in `router.js`:

```
function userCheck(req){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            user.check(req, resolve, reject);
        });
    }

    userCheck(req).then(result => {
        console.log("promise result");
        res.send(result);
    }, error => {
        console.log("promise error");
        res.send(error);
    });
```